# how to count number of array elements that lie between two elements of given array

Tags: java, list, iterator

I want to write a method that when supplied an array of ints will do the following.  For each pair of array elements it will combine them and put them into a list of an inner class objects.  Then it will compare each element in the array and check if it will fit between each pair values. (i.e. I have an array 0, 2, 4 it will make for example pair (0,4) and then it will check that value 2 is indeed between 0 and 4 so counter will increase).  I tried the following code but it returned 0.  How to fix it or is there an easier way to achieve that?  I mainly care for the return value to be correct.  thank you

```
import java.util.*;
import java.util.Map;
import java.lang.*;

public class Prac1 {
    public int count(int[] A){
        int k = 0;
        class PTemp{        
            int first = -1;
            int second = -1;
            public PTemp(int first, int second){
                int f = first;
                int s = second;             
            }           
        }
        List<PTemp> r = new ArrayList<PTemp>();
        for (int i = 0; i < A.length; i++) {
              for (int j = i+1; j < A.length; j++) {
                  r.add(new PTemp(A[i], A[j]));
                  r.add(new PTemp(A[j], A[i]));
                  //System.out.println("["+A[i] +","+A[j]+"]");
                  //System.out.println("["+A[j] +","+A[i]+"]");
              }
            }
        Iterator<PTemp> ir = r.iterator();
        while (ir.hasNext()){
            PTemp p = ir.next();
            for (int i = 0; i < A.length; i++){
                if (((p.first < A[i]) && (A[i] < p.second)) || ((p.first > A[i]) && (A[i] > p.second))){
                    k = k + 1;
                }
            }       
        }               
        return k;
    }
    public static void main(String[] args){
        int[] A = {0, 2, 4};
        Prac1 pr = new Prac1();
        System.out.println(pr.count(A));
    }
}
```

Comment: Why are you adding `PTemp(j,i)` as well as `PTemp(i,j)`?

Comment: He wants to find how many values in the array are between another pair of values from the same array, so he needs both.

Comment: The same amount of values lie between [0,2] and [2,0], so you don't need both.

Comment: yes I know, but left it from some previous exercise.  This is not the main focus though;)

Comment: Are you trying to count values only if they are between the two array indexes or any value in the array that is between the two values? If you have {2, 1, 3, 4} and your pair is {1,4}, should 2 be counted or just 3?

Comment: only between two values in a pair but for each pair.  For your array and pair it should be 2 (+2 for pair 4,1).

Comment: @HunterMcMillen, if you look at how he wrote the test in the final loop, he does need both.

Comment: This loop should be `i < A.length -1`... `for (int i = 0; i < A.length; i++) {`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found a second bug in addition to the one mentioned by Alex D:

```
class PTemp{        
        int first = -1;
        int second = -1;
        public PTemp(int first, int second){
            int f = first;
            int s = second;             
        }           
    }
```

should really be:

```
class PTemp{        
        int first = -1;
        int second = -1;
        public PTemp(int first, int second){
            this.first = first;
            this.second = second;             
        }           
    }
```

Now the fields are properly set.

Comment: yep that was it - think one of my previous version had it like this, but then I remove it for some reason (lol it was close then).  thank you will lvl up your rep

Answer (score 2):

I just saw the bug. This:

```
r.add(new PTemp(i, j));
r.add(new PTemp(j, i));
```

should be:

```
r.add(new PTemp(A[i], A[j]));
r.add(new PTemp(A[j], A[i]));
```

EDIT: It looks like other posters found another bug. I'm glad that your code is working now, but please note that it will be very, *very* slow if you use it on a very large array. I have posted a way to make it fast, even on huge arrays, as an answer to your other, related question.

Comment: yeah sorry I have pasted wrong version (have corrected that in my IDE).  For now I want to achieve it, but it may be used on very large arrays as well.  Do you suspect any computational problems?

Comment: that is interesting I will try to implement that.  I will up your rep.  If you want please help me optimizing the final version here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9048983/how-to-optimize-query-on-how-to-count-number-of-array-elements-that-dont-have-v

Answer (score 2):

The problem is here:

```
 class PTemp
 {        
    int first = -1;
    int second = -1;
    public PTemp(int first, int second)
    {
       int f = first; //error
       int s = second; //error      
    }           
 }
```

On the lines where I marked error, you set `int f` and `int s` equal to `first` and `second`, the problem with this is that the attributes for your class `PTemp` are called `first` and `second` not `f` and `s`.

Change to this and try again:

```
     class PTemp
     {        
        int first = -1;
        int second = -1;

        public PTemp(int first, int second)
        {
           this.first = first;
           this.second = second;             
        }           
     }
```