# how to optimize query on how to count number of array elements that don't have values between them

Tags: java, optimization

I want to write a method that when supplied an array of ints will do the following. For each pair of array elements it will combine them and put them into a list of an inner class objects. Then it will compare each element in the array and check if it will fit between each pair values. (i.e. I have an array 0, 2, 4 it will make for example pair (0,4) and then it will check that value 2 is indeed between 0 and 4 and so for pair (4,0).  When pair (0, 2) is evaluated it won't find anything and therefore counter will increase (and so for pair (2, 0)).   I have constructed the following code to evaluate number of values that indeed will fit in pairs and I hoped then to get the total number of pairs that match my need by extracting it from the total number of pairs.  Now I want to optimize this query (in case I have very big arrays with thousands of members and very big or negative integers e.g. 1,000,000,000 or - 2,000,000,000).  Please let me know how to do that.  Mainly please focus on optimization issues thank you.

```
import java.util.*;
import java.util.Map;
import java.lang.*;

public class Prac1 {
    public int count(int[] A){
        int k = 0;
        class PTemp{        
            int first = 0;
            int second = 0;
            public PTemp(int first, int second){
                this.first = first;
                this.second = second;               
            }   
        }
        List<PTemp> r = new ArrayList<PTemp>();
        int z = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < A.length; i++) {
              for (int j = i+1; j < A.length; j++) {
                  r.add(new PTemp(A[i], A[j]));
                  r.add(new PTemp(A[j], A[i]));
                  z = z + 2;
                  System.out.println("["+A[i] +","+A[j]+"]");
                  System.out.println("["+A[j] +","+A[i]+"]");
              }
            }
        Iterator<PTemp> ir = r.iterator();
        while (ir.hasNext()){
            PTemp p = ir.next();
            label1:
            for (int i = 0; i < A.length-1; i++){

                if (((p.first < A[i]) && (A[i] < p.second)) || ((p.first > A[i]) && (A[i] > p.second))){
                    k = k + 1;
                    break label1;
                }
            }           
        }
        System.out.println(z);
        k = z - k;
        return k;       
    }
    public int c(int[] A) {
         int z = (A.length - 1) * 2;
         return z;
        }
    public static void main(String[] args){
        int[] A = {0, 2, 2, 6, 5, 5};
        Prac1 pr = new Prac1();
        System.out.println(pr.count(A));
        System.out.println(pr.c(A));
    }
}
```

Comment: needed to update my code with some small bug fixed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without loss of generality, we can consider the array to be sorted. Assuming all numbers in the array are distinct, the pairs without elements in between are the pairs formed by neighbours. There are (array.length - 1) * 2 such pairs, i.e. you could simply do:

```
public int count(int[] A) {
   return (A.length - 1) * 2;
}
```

If the array may contain duplicates, you should specify how they are to be counted.

Comment: that is a very good answer.  However am trying to make it work also for arrays with duplicates (i.e. two same values and each counted with its neighbor)

Comment: so if you have an array {0, 2, 2, 6, 5, 5}; returned value (according to my calculation) would be 20) (now my method returns 10 though:()

Comment: yours is 10 as well..., which is sadly not satisfactory for my computation

Comment: actually sorry my method returns 10 but that is ok as it is the number of k (with //k = z - k commented out).  Then when I not comment it it returns correct number that is 20

Answer (score 0):

Sort the array. Make a single pass over the array, identifying groups of equal elements. For each such group, multiply the number of elements in the group, the number of smaller elements, and the number of larger elements. Add that to a running count.

```
public int count(int[] A) {
  int i = 0, k = 0, j = 0;
  Arrays.sort(A); // you need to import java.util.Arrays
  while(i < A.length) {
    for(j = i+1; j < A.length && A[j] == A[i]; j++);
    k += (j - i) * i * (A.length - j);
    i = j;
  }
  return k;
}
```